# TFS non consecutive changesets to merge as single commit

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge

I need to make a software release but I'm having issues with non consecutive changesets. I have almost 20 of them that need to pass from testing environment to production and I've already looked for many solutions.

My main problem is that I'm trying to keep Production branch clean so I want to merge all of those 20 changesets but push them to production as a single commit. I think it will also be easier to rollback if needed. Thing is that you cannot merge a changeset if it detects conflicts on another merge that is yet to be check-in.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well you can't merge changeset directly. It's impossible. Could you create a  independent branch for this situation.